# Return max record of each group with criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of data in Google Sheets from which I need to pull out the max value along with one other corresponding value for multiple groups.

For example, here is a representation of what the sheet looks like:

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
|  Team   | Player | Home Runs |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Mets    | John   |         9 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Yankees | Edward |         3 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Red Sox | Mike   |         1 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Mets    | Joe    |         2 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Mets    | Geoff  |         4 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Yankees | Max    |         7 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Yankees | Danny  |         5 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Red Sox | Clint  |         0 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Red Sox | Clyde  |         8 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

And the result set I would like:

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
|  Team   | Player | Home Runs |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Mets    | John   |         9 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Yankees | Max    |         7 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Red Sox | Clyde  |         8 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

If I were writing a SQL query, I would try to use the `row_number` window function to order the players by team, and then select only the top value per team. I know there is a Query function in Sheets, but I'm not sure if there is a way to write a window function or use `row_number` within that function. Perhaps there is another SQL-esque method here that does not require a window function as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two formulas:

```
=QUERY(A2:C10, "select * order by A,C desc")
//highlighted cell
```

and

```
=FILTER(G2:I12,G2:G12<>G1:G11)
```

[image: Spreadsheet formula screenshot]

Combined into one formula in one cell:

```
=FILTER(QUERY(A1:C11,"select * order by A,C"),{QUERY(A1:C10,"select A order by A,C");""}<>{"";QUERY(A1:C10,"select A order by A,C")})
```

[image: Spreadsheet combined formula screenshot]

Comment: Rereading your question, I see you don't just want the top three. You want the top of each team? I'll think of something else.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if unclear -- but that's right, I'd like to return the top player of each team (ranked by home runs in the above example).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to use vlookup on the unique team names on a sorted table. Something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A:A), sort(A:C, 3, 0), {1, 2, 3}, 0)))
```